# use csv to write two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I need to write two dictionaries into a csv, I want to write the first dictionary in ordered manner and the second dictionary order doesn't matter,
the keys for the second dictionary are cookies from selenium driver and for  I don't know how many keys each site will return (it varies for each website)

```
user1= {'ID':1,'Name':'John','Age':13} # the order I want to keep those must come first
cookies_data = driver.get_cookies() # dictionary
with open('file.csv','w') as csvFile:
    #write to file in this order id,name,age,cookies


# A sample of cookies:
#cookies_data = [{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID', 'path': '/',}] 
#cookies_data can have more than one dictionary and some of the keys may be the same
```

Comment: how does `cookies_data` look like? can u add an example of that, as well as how the csv should look like

Comment: are you expecting to have the same `order id,name,age` values for all final csv records?

Comment: Use [**`DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes the csv must start with id,name,age then cookies doesn't matter

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I added

Comment: so one cookies_data dict per user?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh one file for each website, each website will return the same cookies keys

Comment: Thanks @hadesfv I have tried to come with an answer based on what you said, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write your csv, picking the names of the columns and the values from the combined dictionary and using them to write the csv, while looping over the `cookies_data` list

```
#Combine fieldnames of both dictionaries
fieldnames = list(user1.keys()) + list(cookies_data[0].keys())

#Open csv file
with open('file.csv','w') as csvFile:

    #Write the header and write the combined dictionary
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    #Loop over the cookies_data list and write the combined dict to csv
    for data in cookies_data:
        new_dict = {**user1, **data}
        writer.writerow(new_dict)
```

The output will be

```
ID,Name,Age,domain,expiry,httpOnly,name,path,secure,value
1,John,13,.....
1,John,13,.....
1,John,13,.....
1,John,13,.....
```

Comment: this will returnt  this order (id,name,age,..) regradless of cookies keys?

Comment: also this assumes that length of cookies is one (this isn't always the case)?

Comment: yes 99% of times of cookies_data is more than one dictionary (some of the keys may repeat as well )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195410/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-devesh-kumar-singh).

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas to read the dictionary, create the Dataframe, and then export to csv.

```
import pandas as pd


user1= {'ID':1,'Name':'John','Age':13}
cookies_data = [{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID', 'path': '/'}] 

#to avoid overriding if cookies_data[0] has same keys as cookies_data[1]
cookies = {}
for cookie in cookies_data:
    for c in list(cookie.keys()):
        if c in list(cookies.keys()):
            new_c = str(c) + str(cookies_data.index(cookie))
            cookies.update({new_c : cookie[c]})
        else:
            cookies.update({c : cookie[c]})


user1.update(cookies)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(user1, orient='index')
print(df)

df.to_csv('something.csv')
```

output:

```
ID                 1
Name            John
Age               13
domain    google.com
expiry    1.6243e+09
httpOnly        True
name            ANID
path               /
```

you can add to the dataframe using pd.concat as well:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)
```

output:

```
ID                 1           1
Name            John        John
Age               13          13
domain    google.com  google.com
expiry    1.6243e+09  1.6243e+09
httpOnly        True        True
name            ANID        ANID
path               /           /
```

full code example:

```
import pandas as pd



def get_df(user1, cookies_data):
    cookies = {}
    for cookie in cookies_data:
        for c in list(cookie.keys()):
            if c in list(cookies.keys()):
                new_c = str(c) + str(cookies_data.index(cookie))
                cookies.update({new_c : cookie[c]})
            else:
                cookies.update({c : cookie[c]})
    user1.update(cookies)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(user1, orient='index')
    return df



def main():
    user1 = {'ID':1,'Name':'Rob','Age':17}
    cookies_data = [{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID', 'path': '/'}]
    df1 = get_df(user1, cookies_data)
    user2 = {'ID':1,'Name':'John','Age':13}
    cookies_data2 = [{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID'}]
    df2 = get_df(user2, cookies_data2)
    new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    print(new_df)
    new_df.to_csv('something.csv')

main()
```

output:

```
Age               17          13
ID                 1           1
Name             Rob        John
domain    google.com  google.com
expiry    1.6243e+09  1.6243e+09
httpOnly        True        True
name            ANID        ANID
path               /         NaN
```

can also use a four loop in main function to loop over the users:

```
def main():
all_users = [{'ID':1,'Name':'Rob','Age':17}, {'ID':1,'Name':'John','Age':13}]
all_cookies_data = [[{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID', 'path': '/'}], [{'domain': 'google.com', 'expiry': 1624301720.007404, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'ANID'}]]
need_dfs = list(zip(all_users, all_cookies_data))

dfs_to_concat = []
for dfs in need_dfs:
    new_df = get_df(*dfs)
    dfs_to_concat.append(new_df)

new_df = pd.concat(dfs_to_concat, axis=1)
print(new_df)
new_df.to_csv('something.csv')
```

Comment: this assumes that len(cookies) is 1 ?

Comment: I just assumed that was the case because of the example you posted, but if not always length one, just use a for loop to combine. Updated to reflect that

Comment: how will this deal if cookies[0] have same keys as cookies[1] ?

Comment: fixed it so it wouldn't override. Now if cookies[1] has key "domain" and cookies[0] has key "domain" it will rename the key of cookies[1] to "domain1"

Comment: each dictionary in cookies for one user will be a separate row right?
what will happen if I add more users (list of dictionary in cookies will be the same)

Comment: yes! I just posted a full code example to show you how that would work. Also the nice thing about using the pandas method rather than csv is that if one user has "path" in their dictionary and another does not, it will map it to the correct place automatically based on the keys and then fill in missing values with 'NAN' (showed above)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195412/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-anna-nevison).